# How to get individual text elements from a XML request in jQuery Ajax request

Tags: jquery, xml, forms, response

I am trying to get the text out of XML returned from an Ajax jQuery request but for some reason I can't get at it.

Here is my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendData()
{

    var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var ln = document.getElementById("last_name").value;

    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'scripts/contact.php',
    data: { first_name: fn, last_name: ln },
    success: function(returned){

            $(returned).find('data').each(function(){

            var $data = $(this);
            var first_name = $data.attr("first_name");

            alert("it worked: " + first_name);

            });

        }
    });
}
</script>
```

And here is my PHP page that does the processing (simplified, just trying to get the basics to work):

```
<?php

echo "
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<data>
<first_name>First</first_name>
<last_name>Last</last_name>
</data>

";

?>
```

Appreciate the help. This is driving me mad.

Works now, thank you. Here it is working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendData()
{

    var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var ln = document.getElementById("last_name").value;

    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'scripts/contact.php',
    data: { first_name: fn, last_name: ln },
    success: success
    });
}

function success(success)
{
    var xml = $.parseXML(success);
    $xml = $( xml );
    $test = $xml.find('first_name');
    alert($test.text());

    $last_name = $xml.find('last_name');
    alert($last_name.text());
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried parsing `returned` with `$.parseXML`?

Comment: try with adding **dataType : "xml"** in ajax call

Comment: I tried the $.parseXML and that seems to be working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

giv a try to this

```
$(returned).find('data').each(function(){
    var $data = $(this);
    var first_name = $data.find("first_name").text();

    alert("it worked: " + first_name);
});
```